# Grunt: Error: Cannot find module './util/task'

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I am having a problem getting grunt to work on my linux box. I checked the node_modules folder and there is a folder missing from the grunt source. This does not happen on my local machine.

Grunt is installed globally but seems to be having this problem when installing locally.

My Grunt version is 0.4.5

Is there a problem with grunt and linux?

```
Error: Cannot find module './util/task'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/my_project/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:28:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run `npm install` from the directory where you want to run grunt.

Comment: I ended up getting it worked out (still not sure exactly why it was happening). The modules were installed locally it was just that one folder that was missing out of the local grunt folder under node_modules. Thanks Though!!!